# Postgres filtering by field from other table if condition

Tags: postgresql

I have query like:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN type IN (2,10) THEN (select dr from s_d where server_id=s.id) 
        ELSE dr END AS dr
FROM s
WHERE dr in (1,2,3)
```

'dr' field exists in both tables. So when 'type' field in (1,2) it filtering by s.dr (need by s_d.dr). How can I do it with JOIN?

```
table s:
     id (int)
     type (int)
     dr (int)

table s_d:
     id (int)
     server_id (int)
     dr (int)
```

Comment: Can you provide even minimal example in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Please provide both tables (as little example) and desirable result

Comment: Table structures appended

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id,
    case
        when type in (2,10) then sd.dr 
        else s.dr
    end as dr
from
    s
    inner join
    s_d sd on sd.server_id = s.id      
where s.dr in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: It will filter by sd.dr when type in (2,10) as I need?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetzyanov Did you try it?

Comment: No, I can test it only on production. Unfortunately(

Comment: @IldarAkhmetzyanov So what is preventing you from testing?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id,
    case
        when type in (2,10) then sd.dr 
        else s.dr
    end as dr
from s
left join s_d sd on sd.server_id = s.id      
where s.dr in (1,2,3)
```

Contrary to the answer from @Clodoaldo my solution would return null as dr for rows, where not corresponding row in s_d table to the s row exists, in the solution from @Clodoaldo such rows are filtered out.
It depends on your requirements, which answer is correct for your case.